# .on('click') event for a single JSON layer, how to?

Tags: javascript, json, onclick, openlayers

I'm stuck with a problem that I can't find anywhere else on the internet. Or atleast not what I mean.

In my part of code I have made a popup with an map.on('click') event, however I would like the event to be only possible with one layer and only when that layer is active. As you can see in my code I also want my sidebar to open a tab when the layer is clicked, however now when you click the map anywhere the sidebar will still open.
The layer that I want the sidebar to react to is called: "bottlenecklayer"
The next code is what I currently have, the code at the bottom shows what I've tried as well but did not work.

```
 map.on('click', function(evt){
     
     var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
       function(feature) {
         
         return feature;
       
      });
       
      document.getElementById("sidebar").classList.toggle("collapsed");
      document.getElementById("pop-up-message").classList.toggle("active");
    
       
     if (feature) {
         var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
         var coord = geometry.getCoordinates();
         var imagebottleneckbefore = feature.get('Image_before');
         var imagebottleneckafter = feature.get('Image_after');
        
     
    
     /* if (imagebottleneckbefore === null)
         {imagebottleneckbefore = "hidden"};*/
        
     if (imagebottleneckafter === null)
         {imagebottleneckafter =  "otterplaceholde.jpg"};
         
     if (imagebottleneckafter === "nopic")
         {imagebottleneckafter =  "otterplaceholde.jpg"};
         
     if (feature.get('Description') === null)
         {return "Er is geen beschrijving bij dit knelpunt."};
    
    
         var contentjson = '<h2 >' + "Knelpunt:" + '&nbsp;' + feature.get('Name') + '</h2>';
        /* contentjson += "<img src='img/bottleneckpictures/"+imagebottleneckbefore+"' style='width:260px; height:130px;'>";*/
         contentjson += '&nbsp'
         contentjson += "<img src='img/bottleneckpictures/"+imagebottleneckafter+"' style='width:260px; height:130px;'>";
         contentjson += '<p class="lorem" >' +  feature.get('Description') + '</p>';
        // contentjson += '<h3>' + feature.get('Descriptionholder') + '</h3>';
         content_elementjson.innerHTML = contentjson;
       
     }
     
     
    });
```

This is the part of code that does not work either:

```
bottlenecklayer.on('click',function(evt){ 
  document.getElementById("sidebar").classList.toggle("collapsed");
  document.getElementById("pop-up-message").classList.toggle("active")
});
```

Comment: Hi, could you please share your HTML?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a `layerFilter` function in the `forEachFeatureAtPixel` request:

```
 var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
   function(feature) {
     
     return feature;
   
  }, {

     layerFilter: function(layer) {
        return layer === bottlenecklayer;
     }

  });
```

Layers do not have click events.

Comment: THanks for your help, maybe you could help me some more.
The code kind of works but not properly. See my code atm below:

map.on('click', function(evt){
 
 var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
   function(feature) {
     
     return feature}, 
     {
     layerFilter: function(layer){
       return layer.get(layer) === bottlenecklayer.feature,
       
       document.getElementById("sidebar").classList.toggle("collapsed"),
       document.getElementById("pop-up-message").classList.toggle("active");
       
      }
  });